# Xamarin.Android - How do you set the MONO_GC_PARAMS environment variable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How do you set the value of this environment variable in Mac OSX? I tried creating an environment.txt file in my Xamarin.Android project with a build action of AndroidEnvironment, but when I check my diagnostic build output, I still see this:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS = major=marksweep-conc
```

I didn't set that value - it must be the default, but I can't find where it's stored or how to change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These items need to be on a single line with commas seperating the parameters. i.e. `MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=tarjan,nursery-size=128‌​m,soft-heap-limit=51‌​2m,major=marksweep-c‌​onc`

This will be picked up via the following [code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/d80b485bcbc6dff29dbd79aa2423f283dd62c60a/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Tasks/BuildApk.cs#L384-L385):

```
if (lineToWrite.StartsWith ("MONO_GC_PARAMS=", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        haveMonoGCParams = true;
```

You should be able to set this item if you have the `Use the concurrent garbage collector (Experimental)` enabled in your project settings. This definition will be added to your `.csproj`:

```
<AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
```

This will set the following parameter to Mono:

```
if (!haveMonoGCParams) {
                if (EnableSGenConcurrent)
                    environment.WriteLine ("MONO_GC_PARAMS=major=marksweep-conc");
                else
                    environment.WriteLine ("MONO_GC_PARAMS=major=marksweep");
            }
```

[Source](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/d80b485bcbc6dff29dbd79aa2423f283dd62c60a/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Tasks/BuildApk.cs#L417)

However I believe only two options are available via this logic. Either `marksweep` or `marksweep-conc`.