# Increase Major heap in Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Is there a way to increase your major-heap garbage collector in Xamarin forms and if so where to I set this

I have found this code major=marksweep-fixed,major-heap-size=2g

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Mono's env. var in each of the application projects and both platforms (iOS and Android) are different in how that is done.

#### Xamarin.Android Environment

> An environment file is a Unix-formatted plain-text file with a Build action of `AndroidEnvironment`. The environment file contains lines with the format key=value. Comments are lines which start with #. Blank lines are ignored.
>
> if key starts with an uppercase letter, then key is treated as an environment variable and setenv(3) is used to set the environment variable to the specified value during process startup.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/environment

#### Xamarin.iOS Environment

> Permanent environment variables are set by specifying extra arguments to the mtouch packaging tool. These environment variables are compiled into the executable

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/environment

Also review this SO from Jon Douglas:

- [Xamarin.Android - How do you set the MONO_GC_PARAMS environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539289/xamarin-android-how-do-you-set-the-mono-gc-params-environment-variable)